# counter not inceasing in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have looked at other while loops and am stuck on why this one is not working.

```
points = int(input('How many points: '))
while True:
    u_cnt, c_cnt = 0, 0
    if u_cnt < points or c_cnt < points:
        if u < c:
            c_cnt += 1
        elif u > c:
            u_cnt += 1
```

Is my problems having the `c_cnt += 1` inside of two if statements?

I have put it outside of the `while` loop, yet that doesn't increase count either. I have also put the `u_cnt = 0` and `c_cnt = 0` on separate lines.

It's not doing an infinite loop, as it should not do. It's just not incrementing.

Thank you

edit:

```
import random

u_name = input('What is your name? ')
points = int(input('How many points: '))
u_cnt, c_cnt = 0, 0

while True:
    a = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    comp = random.choice(a)
    print('Pick from:', str(a).strip('[]'))
    user = input()
    u = a.index(user)
    c = a.index(comp)
    line_1 = '{} : {}\t{} : {}'.format(u_name, user, 'Computer', comp)
    line_2 = '{} : {}\t{} : {}\n'.format(u_name, u_cnt, 'Computer', c_cnt)

    if c_cnt < points or u_cnt < points:
        if u > c or u == 0 and c == 2:
            u_cnt += 1
            print(line_1, '\t', u_name, 'wins')
            print(line_2)
        elif u < c or u == 2 and c == 0:
            c_cnt += 1
            print(line_1, '\t', 'Computer wins')
            print(line_2)
        elif u == c:
            print(line_1, '\t', 'Tie')
            print(line_2)
    else:
        break
```

so when you run this the first time, you get an answer back like

```
What is your name? chad
How many points: 3
Pick from: 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'
rock
chad : rock Computer : scissors      chad wins
chad : 0    Computer : 0

Pick from: 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'
```

how to get the count be 1, 0 on the first iteration through.  that might be a better question.

Comment: You are resetting the counters to zero each time you enter the loop. Put the `u_cnt, c_cnt = 0, 0` before the `while`.

Comment: i doubt that "It's not doing an infinite loop" since there is no mechanism to get out of the loop.

Comment: @JulienSpronck Agreed. How can that code EVER break out of the loop?

There is no "break" and no "raise..." statements so it can never get out.

Comment: When you put stuff in a loop, please ask yourself if it couldn't be placed *outside* of it. What is the goal of redefining `a = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]` each round?

Comment: @Efferalgan, thank you for that point.  now that I know that, I could actually put line_2 out_side of the while loop also,  since none of the variables are being called before it, correct? as with line_1 where some of the variables are being created from what the choices are. i have to have that inside the while.  Are `while` loops the hardest to get the hang of? for specific boolean logic that is?

Answer (score 1):

The code have to be right there:

```
points = int(input('How many points: '))
u_cnt, c_cnt = 0, 0 # asign the values before the loop
while True:
    if u_cnt < points or c_cnt < points:
        if u < c:
            c_cnt += 1
        elif u > c:
            u_cnt += 1
```

Comment: This is doing an infinite loop.

Comment: because you are using `if` and `elif`. Depends of your `u` and `c` values the code never will enter to your `if` or `elif` sentence, you could try using only `else:` insted of `elif u > c:`, Also you can test the loop printing the value before every evaluation: `print ("u_cnt: ",u_cnt)`

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the counters to 0 every time you run the loop again so it may increment but it will just get rest to zero. To fix this you can move your variable declarations outside of the loop:

```
points = int(input('How many points: '))
u_cnt, c_cnt = 0, 0
while True:
  if u_cnt < points or c_cnt < points:
      if u < c:
          c_cnt += 1
      elif u > c:
          u_cnt += 1
```

You are also have no method to exit the loop. You need to add in a **break** to exit the loop. For example:

```
while True:
  if some_condition:
    break
```

Comment: "true" is not defined

Comment: @JulienSpronck I fixed it. I am answering this on my iPad so it is pretty hard to type code

Comment: No worries ;-) i just edited the indentation as well

Comment: @PabloAlejandro and aiden, thank you.  I do have a break at the end of the loop.  just didn't put it into the example.

Comment: I said thank you to soon.  I'll post the full script and then make comments on that.

Answer (score 0):

Writing all this out in hopes that it helps other beginners like me.  If others can explain it better than I do please comment.

So this was a python beginner practice problem from-
http://openbookproject.net/pybiblio/practice/wilson/rockpaperscissors.php
I didn't put the ctrl-d into it though.

I'll make comments on the code that worked how I wanted it to.  That is give the count as each try was went through.

```
import random

u_name = input('What is your name? ')
points = int(input('How many points to play to? '))
u_cnt, c_cnt = 0, 0
a = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

while u_cnt < points or c_cnt < points:
    comp = random.choice(a)
    print('Pick from:', str(a).strip('[]'))
    user = input()
    u = a.index(user)
    c = a.index(comp)
    line_1 = '{} : {}\t{} : {}'.format(u_name, user, 'Computer', comp)
    if u > c or u == 0 and c == 2:
        u_cnt += 1
        print(line_1, '\t', u_name, 'wins')
    elif u < c or u == 2 and c == 0:
        c_cnt += 1
        print(line_1, '\t', 'Computer wins')
    elif u == c:
        print(line_1, '\t', 'Tie')

    line_2 = '{} : {}\t{} : {}\n'.format(u_name, u_cnt, 'Computer', c_cnt)
    print(line_2)
    if u_cnt == points or c_cnt == points:
        if u_cnt > c_cnt:
            print('\n', u_name.upper(), 'WINS!!!')
        elif u_cnt < c_cnt:
            print('\n', 'COMPUTER WINS!!!')
        print(line_2)
        break

exit()
```

To get my count for each attempt I had to put `line_2` at the end of my first `if` loop so that it would increment properly.

If you look at my original post, you will see that I have `line_2` outside of the first `if` statement.  This was making it so that it would go through the whole loop and then add the count the next time through, instead of adding it right away.

I put the second `if` statement in so that it would test the loop and then print who the winner was.

I also learned that I had alot of extra `print(line_2)` statements in the original post and if I just put the one in I could reduce my typing. (pythonic way?)

I have done this (rock, paper, scissors) on other practice sites and this is the least amount of `if, elif`'s that I have had to do.

As the people who know what they are doing will tell you, practice code, read code, practice code.

Thank you everyone for your help and tips/tricks.
em